# How to send data from one sheet then to another when submit is pressed?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I am creating an Excel project and am having some trouble inputting data from one sheet to another. I need the invoice from sheet1 to be transferred into a table in sheet2 which has the customer details (first name, surname, house number, postcode, contact number).

So, every time I fill in the cells and click the "Submit" button after filling out the fields in the creating a new invoice page, it automatically transfers into the Customer Details page after clicking a "Submit" button.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  There are lots of examples and discussions about doing exactly what you're describing, but I understand that when starting out, it can be tricky to even know where to start looking.  [Here's a search](https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&q=Excel+copy+data+to+different+sheet+on+command+button+click) to get you started.  If you get stuck on a _specific_ issue, feel free to [edit] your code to show what you've tried so far.  (See also: "[mcve]" and "[topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)".)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this on a submit button. The section saying back and front range, you just need to change it to suit your needs. For example if Customer name was on your Front sheet in cell A1, with this it would place a copy in the back sheet in cell A2. You can add as many as you want and VBA will just cycle through moving them into the range you are after.

```
Option Explicit
sub example ()
Dim wb as thisworkbook
Dim Front as worksheet("Sheet1")
Dim Back as worksheet("Sheet2")

Back.Range("A2") = Front.range("A1")

End Sub
```